# How do I exclude a folder from AWS Codebuild buildspec file?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-codebuild

So I need to exclude a folder from my artifacts, but googling around could not find any info.

```
version: 0.2

phases:
  install:
    runtime-versions:
      nodejs: 10
  build:
    commands:
    - echo Build started on `date`
     - echo Compiling the Node.js code
     - mocha test.js

  post_build:
    commands:
      - echo Build completed on `date`
artifacts:
  files:
    - '**/*'
```

Comment: What about just removing the unneeded files or folders in post_build stage?

Comment: @Marcin oh, you mean just `rm -rf myfolder/` ? That is not a bad idea actually.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[buildspec.yaml](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codebuild/latest/userguide/build-spec-ref.html#build-spec-ref-syntax) does not provide a way to skip some files or folders when constructing artifacts.

Thus, based on the comments, the easiest solution to the problem was to simply **delete unneeded files and folders** in the `post_build` stage.

Answer (score 8):

buildspec.yml currently support excluding paths in the artifacts section.

```
  artifacts:
    exclude-paths: 
      - ./**/someFilePatternHere
      - ./**/otherFilePatternHere
```

It follows the same logic as the files: section but does exclude particular files.
See:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codebuild/latest/userguide/build-spec-ref.html#build-spec.artifacts.exclude-paths

ps: exclude-paths is relative to base-directory property.

Comment: Be careful with the indentation - `exclude-paths` is a property of `artifacts` and should be indented.

Answer (score -1):

1 Solution = exclude in .gitingnore file.
2 Solution = add this in below your code.
  Let me know if it works

artifacts:
  files:
    - '**/*'
  excluded_paths:
    - foldername/*

Comment: Can I ask how did you came up with `exluded_paths`? Reference [doc](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codebuild/latest/userguide/build-spec-ref.html#build-spec-ref-syntax) for the builspec.yml does not mention this.

Comment: it works in GitLab, thats why I asked let me know if it works. Also, you can ignore it in .gitignore