# CodeBuild pushes source React files to s3 instead of the build folder

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-codebuild

im using CodePipeline with CodeBuild together with a github repository.

CodeBuild builds the project successfully, but he uploads the source react folder like the whole repository without any build folder to S3.

My buildspec.yaml looks like this:

```
version: 0.2

phases:
  build:
    commands:
      - echo "Installing dependicies..."
      - npm install 
      - echo "Create the build..."
      - npm run build
artifacts:
  files:
    - '**/*'
  base-directory: 'build'
```

What can I do ?

Comment: did you see the cloudwatch logs for anything unusual?

Comment: Yeah logs are here: https://prnt.sc/u148g7 @MuhammadHasan

Comment: No nothing was unusual

Comment: strange. Are you sure the artifact that you saw was the build artifact and not the source artifact? I think you saw the source artifact and thought it to be the build artifact. please confirm.

Comment: Do u mean on s3 or where ?! On S3 i see the raw github repository, means the source. I dont see the build artifact anywhere. Can you contact me on discord ? my name is prodigy#7662 @MuhammadHasan

Comment: sorry. i dont use discord.

Comment: in the s3 for your pipeline there are 2 dirs. one contains source artifacts and one has your build artifacts. you need to find the build artifacts. they must be getting stored in the s3. i'm not sure about the name of the s3,

Comment: @MuhammadHasan and where do we can write further ? Like its still not working, help :(

Comment: in my s3 bucket i only see this here: https://prnt.sc/u14y1p @MuhammadHasan 
I dont see any build folder

Comment: are you sure thats the s3 being used by your pipeline? because codepipeline creates its own dir structure in the s3 and the artifact should be in the zip format

Comment: Ah there is really a codepipeline folder but I specified a other s3 bucket for this pipeline, when i open the pipeline s3 bucket not the bucket i specified in the pipeline it shows me this:

https://prnt.sc/u151so and https://prnt.sc/u151xj

Comment: yes. these random names are your build artifacts. if you download them they should be in zip foirmat. you'll find the build files there.

Comment: Yeah its. I dont want to create them manually and put them manually to s3 every time. My Question is why they're not in the s3 bucket i specified???

Comment: last time i checked. when you make the build project part of the codepipeline. codepipeline takes control and even the artifacts names are created by codepipeline by itself.

Comment: Nice, now the build folder is in the s3 bucket!! But also like src folder and public folder of react itself, how can I exclude them ? @MuhammadHasan

Comment: this might be of help. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61406889/how-do-i-exclude-a-folder-from-aws-codebuild-buildspec-file

Comment: @MuhammadHasan My question is how do I delete custom files? they saying this is the solution, but how to haha. And do I have to make all files public? Its unsafe for an static site or normal?

Comment: 1) you can remove those files with the "rm -rf foldername" command. 2) what do you mean by making all files public?

Comment: Im using static website hosting through s3. On all websites they're sayin you have to make all files public accessable that you can visit the website and dont get an "access denied error" , and 2) thanks for the command i will use it!

Comment: okay. i think you're really confused here. the artifacts themselves are not directly exposed. you need to copy the contents of the build folder to s3. make that s3 publicly readable. and you follow these steps to make your s3 able to serve the web content: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/HowDoIWebsiteConfiguration.html

Comment: thanks again, but he didnt deleted any file i specified... :(

Comment: @MuhammadHasan .

Comment: they must have been deleted if you have specified the correct path. otherwise, the build stage would fail.